problemas con Json al agregar una img
Hola Estoy intentando enviar una tabla con datos extraídos de una base en phpMyadmin,todo funciona bien con Json, pero cuando el dato es una imagen no logro visualizarla.
todo funciona bien en cuanto a buscardor o paginación, siempre y cuando no tenga imagenes en la base de datos, las que guardo em phpmyadmin con LONGBLOB, agregue que al subir fotos estas se pueden ver en que formato están para poder ver cuando ocupar base64 (categoriaP y TipoP)
la idea es poder ir creando codigo html al ir pasando el while por la tabla
Por favor si alguien pudiera ayudarme se los agradecería mucho. Gracias
esta es la pagina "(load.php)" donde extraigo toda la información
<?php     

require 'config.php';     

// Columnas a mostrar en la tabla

$columns = ['portada', 'categoriaP', 'tipoP', 'nombre', 'apellido', 'fecha_nacimiento', 'fecha_ingreso'];

// Nombre de la tabla
$table = "empleados";

// Clave principal de la tabla
$id = 'nombre';

// Campo a buscar
$campo = isset($_POST['campo']) ? $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['campo']) : null;

// Filtrado
$where = '';

if ($campo != null) {
    $where = "WHERE (";

    $cont = count($columns);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $cont; $i++) {
        $where .= $columns[$i] . " LIKE '%" . $campo . "%' OR ";
    }
    $where = substr_replace($where, "", -3);
    $where .= ")";
}

// Limites
$limit = isset($_POST['registros']) ? $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['registros']) : 10;
$pagina = isset($_POST['pagina']) ? $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['pagina']) : 0;

if (!$pagina) {
    $inicio = 0;
    $pagina = 1;
} else {
    $inicio = ($pagina - 1) * $limit;
}

$sLimit = "LIMIT $inicio , $limit";

// Ordenamiento

$sOrder = "";
if (isset($_POST['orderCol'])) {
    $orderCol = $_POST['orderCol'];
    $oderType = isset($_POST['orderType']) ? $_POST['orderType'] : 'asc';

    $sOrder = "ORDER BY " . $columns[intval($orderCol)] . ' ' . $oderType;
}

// Consulta
$sql = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS " . implode(", ", $columns) . "
FROM $table
$where
$sOrder
$sLimit";
$resultado = $conn->query($sql);
$num_rows = $resultado->num_rows;

// Consulta para total de registro filtrados
$sqlFiltro = "SELECT FOUND_ROWS()";
$resFiltro = $conn->query($sqlFiltro);
$row_filtro = $resFiltro->fetch_array();
$totalFiltro = $row_filtro[0];

// Consulta para total de registro
$sqlTotal = "SELECT count($id) FROM $table ";
$resTotal = $conn->query($sqlTotal);
$row_total = $resTotal->fetch_array();
$totalRegistros = $row_total[0];

// Mostrado resultados
$output = [];
$output['totalRegistros'] = $totalRegistros;
$output['totalFiltro'] = $totalFiltro;
$output['data'] = '';
$output['paginacion'] = '';

if ($num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {

<!-- ESTO SOLO FUE UNA PRUEBA PARA ASEGURARME DE QUE LA INFO ESTA
        $portada=$row['portada'];
        $categoriaP=$row['categoriaP'];
        $tipoP=$row['tipoP'];

        $valorP="";
        if($categoriaP=='jpg' || $categoriaP=='png'|| $categoriaP=='JPG'|| $categoriaP=='jpeg'|| $categoriaP=='PNG'){
            $valorP="<img width='200' height='200' transform='scale(1.2)'  src='data:image/jpg;base64,".base64_encode($portada)."'>";
        }
echo $valorP;

-->

        $output['data'] .= '<tr>';
        $output['data'] .= '<td> echo"<img src="data:image/jpg;base64," ' .base64_encode( $portada).'>"</td>';
        $output['data'] .= '<td>' . $row['nombre'] . '</td>';
        $output['data'] .= '<td>' . $row['apellido'] . '</td>';
        $output['data'] .= '<td>' . $row['fecha_nacimiento'] . '</td>';
        $output['data'] .= '<td>' . $row['fecha_ingreso'] . '</td>';
        $output['data'] .= '<td><a class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" href="editar.php?id=' . $row['nombre'] . '">Editar</a></td>';
        $output['data'] .= "<td><a class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' href='elimiar.php?id=" . $row['nombre'] . "'>Eliminar</a></td>";
        $output['data'] .= '</tr>';
    }
} else {
    $output['data'] .= '<tr>';
    $output['data'] .= '<td colspan="7">Sin resultados</td>';
    $output['data'] .= '</tr>';
}

// Paginación
if ($totalRegistros > 0) {
    $totalPaginas = ceil($totalFiltro / $limit);

    $output['paginacion'] .= '<nav>';
    $output['paginacion'] .= '<ul class="pagination">';

    $numeroInicio = max(1, $pagina - 4);
    $numeroFin = min($totalPaginas, $numeroInicio + 9);

    for ($i = $numeroInicio; $i <= $numeroFin; $i++) {
        $output['paginacion'] .= '<li class="page-item' . ($pagina == $i ? ' active' : '') . '">';
        $output['paginacion'] .= '<a class="page-link" href="#" onclick="nextPage(' . $i . ')">' . $i . '</a>';
        $output['paginacion'] .= '</li>';
    }

    $output['paginacion'] .= '</ul>';
    $output['paginacion'] .= '</nav>';
}

echo json_encode($output, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);





----------- LUEGO ENVIA LA INFORMACION A LA SIGUIENTE PAGINA-----------


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="description" content="Buscar datos en tiempo real con PHP, MySQL y AJAX">
    <meta name="author" content="Marco Robles">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
    <title>Almacen</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    

</head>
<h1 class="logotipo">Full  Properties</h1>

<a href="/img"><img class="logo" src="img/logo.jpg" ></a>

<header>
        <div class="contenedor">
        <nav>
                <a href="http:///www.fullproperties.cl/vendetucasa.php" class="activo">Vende tu casa</a>
                /
                <a href="http://www.fullproperties.cl/las_condes/las_condes.php">Las Condes</a>
                /
                <a href="http://www.fullproperties.cl/la_reina/la_reina.php">La Reina</a>
                /   
                <a href="http://www.fullproperties.cl/contacto.php">Contacto</a>                        
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>   
<body>

<div class ="mega">
        <main>
            <h3 class="titulo">Encontremos juntos tu hogar</h3>
            <br>
            <br>
            <div class="pelicula-principal">
                <div class="contenedor1">
                    
             </div>
     </div>
        </main>



    <main>
        <div class="propiedades">
            <h2>Casas</h2>

            <div class="tabla1">

                <div class="col-auto text-start">
                    <label for="num_registros" class="col-form-label">Mostrar: </label>
                </div>

                <div class="col-auto text-start">
                    <select name="num_registros" id="num_registros" class="form-select">
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                        <option value="25">25</option>
                        <option value="50">50</option>
                        <option value="100">100</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="col-auto text-start">
                    <label for="num_registros" class="col-form-label">registros </label>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4 col-xl-5"></div>

                <div class="col-6 col-md-1 text-end">
                    <label for="campo" class="col-form-label">Buscar: </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 col-md-3 text-end">
                    <input type="text" name="campo" id="campo" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row py-4">
                <div class="col">
                    <table class="table table-sm table-bordered table-striped">
                        <thead>


                            <th class="sort asc">Id</th>
                            <th class="sort asc">Comuna</th>
                            <th class="sort asc">Precio</th>
                            <th class="sort asc">Dormitorios</th>
                            <th class="sort asc">Baños</th>
                            <th></th>
                            <th></th>
                        </thead>

                        <!-- El id del cuerpo de la tabla. -->
                        <tbody id="content">

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row justify-content-between">

                <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
                    <label id="lbl-total"></label>
                </div>

                <div class="col-12 col-md-4" id="nav-paginacion"></div>

                <input type="hidden" id="pagina" value="1">
                <input type="hidden" id="orderCol" value="0">
                <input type="hidden" id="orderType" value="asc">

            </div>
        </div>
    </main>

    <script>
        // Llamando a la función getData() al cargar la página
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", getData);

        // Función para obtener datos con AJAX
        function getData() {
            let input = document.getElementById("campo").value
            let num_registros = document.getElementById("num_registros").value
            let content = document.getElementById("content")
            let pagina = document.getElementById("pagina").value || 1;
            let orderCol = document.getElementById("orderCol").value
            let orderType = document.getElementById("orderType").value

            let formaData = new FormData()
            formaData.append('campo', input)
            formaData.append('registros', num_registros)
            formaData.append('pagina', pagina)
            formaData.append('orderCol', orderCol)
            formaData.append('orderType', orderType)

            fetch("load4.php", {
                    method: "POST",
                    body: formaData
                })
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    content.innerHTML = data.data
                    document.getElementById("lbl-total").innerHTML = `Mostrando ${data.totalFiltro} de ${data.totalRegistros} registros`;
                    document.getElementById("nav-paginacion").innerHTML = data.paginacion

                    // Si la página actual no tiene resultados, ajustar la paginación para mostrar la primera página
                    if (data.data.includes('Sin resultados') && parseInt(pagina) !== 1) {
                        nextPage(1); // Ir a la primera página
                    }
                })
                .catch(err => console.log(err))
        }

        // Función para cambiar de página
        function nextPage(pagina) {
            document.getElementById('pagina').value = pagina
            getData()
        }

        // Función para ordenar columnas
        function ordenar(e) {
            let elemento = e.target;
            let orderType = elemento.classList.contains("asc") ? "desc" : "asc";

            document.getElementById('orderCol').value = elemento.cellIndex;
            document.getElementById("orderType").value = orderType;
            elemento.classList.toggle("asc");
            elemento.classList.toggle("desc");

            getData()
        }

        // Event listeners para los eventos de cambio en el campo de entrada y el select
        document.getElementById("campo").addEventListener("keyup", getData);
        document.getElementById("num_registros").addEventListener("change", getData);

        // Event listener para ordenar las columnas
        let columns = document.querySelectorAll(".sort");
        columns.forEach(column => {
            column.addEventListener("click", ordenar);
        });
    </script>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JS -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>


Qué problema te da al agregar la imagen? Algún mensaje de error? algún comportamiento inesperado?

no visualizo la imagen, me cuenta como leído toda la tabla con los 150 integrantes, pero no logro ver la imagen en la pagina donde hago AJAX (index.php, el segundo codigo que muestro). Saludos

agregué una imagen para que quede mas claro el problema, donde debería ver la imagen, solo sale que es efectivamente un campo img, pero no visualizo la foto en si.

Seguro que el mimeType es ese? image/jpg? Inspecciona una de esas imágenes ya cuando renderizes y revisa si la base64 está bien

Y es buena idea pasar imágenes "puras" por JSON?? No sería más fácil solo enviar las url??

con respecto a lo que me dice "javdromero "en un momento pensé que el problema podía ser el mimeType, fue una de las cosas que revisé.  también he probado con guardar las imágenes en binario dejando la base de datos en varchar .  Gracias por lo menos se que estoy buscando por los mismos lados que los expertos en el tema.

con respecto a "OCHOA" , como podría hacer lo que propones sin perder la paginación y el buscador manteniendo el id de las imagenes ? Gracias

Tendría que responderte con la estructura que se usa en Wordpress (el mejor ejemplo). Eso si, en la Base debes tener solo las url de las imágenes y no las imágenes per se. Guardar imágenes en la DB nunca es bueno, es mejor solo las url. Si quieres te preparo una respuesta?? PD: se usa @ para mencionar a alguien... @RafaelVentura

el MIME Type no tendría que ser image/jpeg (con una E)?

@OCHOA gracias probare modificar parte del index.php con tu código y creare una URL para las imágenes, las imágenes tengo que guardarlas si o si en mi BD ya que soy corredor de propiedades y estoy subiendo mis propias imágenes de las casas que publico. Saludos

Y eso que? La forma correcta es subir las imágenes a una carpeta (de tu hosting) y guardar la ubicación (url) en la DB. Esa es la forma más optima. La verdad nunca o casi nunca se recomienda guardar las imágenes en la DB.

Este es un pequeño y fácil ejemplo de como manejar información de una API JSON
Voy a ejemplificarlo con una web random en Wordpress de una manera super rápida y sencilla
<?php
    // API Wordpress
    $siteBase = "https://www.ladrilleramelendez.com.co/wp-json/wp/v2/";
    // Leemos el JSON
    $json = file_get_contents($siteBase."producto");
    // Convertimos en un array
    $products = json_decode($json);

    // Probando la data
    /*echo "<pre>";
        print_r($products);
    echo "</pre>";*/
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Rest API SVC</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="text-center mb-3 mt-3">Productos de la Web</h1>
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
                <th scope="col">Imagen</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php foreach ($products as $product){ ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a href="<?php echo $product->link; ?>" target="_blank">
                                <?php echo $product->title->rendered; ?>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php
                                $mediaID = $product->featured_media;
                                $mediaUrl = $siteBase."media/".$mediaID;
                                $mediaJson = file_get_contents($mediaUrl);
                                $media = json_decode($mediaJson);
                            ?>
                            <img src="<?php echo $media->media_details->sizes->thumbnail->source_url; ?>" alt="<?php echo $media->alt_text; ?>" width="75px" title="<?php echo $media->alt_text; ?>">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php } ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

Resultado

Ojo, en este pequeño ejemplo, la web en cuestión no tiene bloqueado el acceso al API (la mayoría de sitios Wordpress están así) y esto permite que cualquiera vea y use esa información.

Otro ejemplo de un API Woocommerce que tengo por ahí (con credenciales), la información se ve mejor y más estructurada.
Articulo - Categoría - Imagen - Precio

